# What it means to say $\pi$ and $e^\pi$ are algebraically independent $?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, definition, pi, transcendental-numbers

$\pi$ and $e^\pi$ are algebraically independent. But what does that mean?

Is that if $a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_n$ and $b_0, b_1, \cdots, b_n$ are algebraic numbers then

$$a_0\pi + a_1\pi + \cdots + a_n\pi + b_0e^\pi+ b_1e^\pi + \cdots + b_ne^\pi$$

is transcendental or $0$ $?$ If the above is wrong, what is the correct form?

Comment: The result is transcendental.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that if $P(x,y)$ is a non-null polynomial with rational coefficients, then $P(\pi,e^\pi)\neq0$.

Comment: That's the olny answer I could understand, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be a field and $K\subseteq L$ a subfield. The elements of a subset $I\subseteq L$ are algebraically independent over $K$ if for every polynomial $p\in K[x]$ one has
$$(\forall x\in I\,p(x) = 0) \Rightarrow p=0. $$
Thus, if we choose $p\neq 0$ (likely over $\mathbb Q$) then $p(\pi) \neq 0$ or $p(e^\pi)\neq 0$.