# Explaining Algebraic Independence of $\delta$ and $\gamma$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, transcendental-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

I have been attempting to read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.1768) by Alexander Aptekarev. In it, he proves that [$\delta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_constant) and [$\gamma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) cannot both be rational simultaneously. He also notes that this result follows from a paper by A.B. Shidlovski, in which it was shown that
$$1-\frac{1}{e}\ \ \text{and}\ \ -\left(\gamma-\frac{\delta}{e}\right)$$
are *algebraically independent*. This is the terminology I am hung upon. Although I am familiar with what an algebraic number is (and hence what transcendental numbers are), I can't seem to wrap my head around what it means for two numbers to be algebraically independent, or from such a statement we can deduce that $\delta$ and $\gamma$ cant both be rational.

When I try to look up algebraic independence, the definitions use terminology that goes way over my head (as I am simply a math undergrad). Is there a way of explaining this concept to a novice like myself in a way that I can understand how from such a statement I can deduce that $\delta$ and $\gamma$ cant both be rational? All insight is appreciated.

Comment: Replace $\pi$ and $e^{\pi}$ by $x$ and $y$,and consult the first (or other) answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3532520/what-it-means-to-say-pi-and-e-pi-are-algebraically-independent?rq=1) for an explanation of what algebraic independence is. Basically, the two shouldn't be "polynomially" related, in the sense that there isn't a polynomial $P$ in two variables  (for example , $P(x,y) = -3x^2+12x^6y-4y^3$) such that $P(1- \frac 1e, -(\gamma - \frac{\delta}{e})) = 0$.